# disable stomp debug output in jhipster

Tags: jhipster, stompjs

I am sitting here for hours to find out how I can disable the debug output of stomp.js.

I am actually getting this output in development + production environment:

```
Web Socket Opened...
webstomp.js?afe9:238 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.2,1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

�
webstomp.js?afe9:238 >>> length 60
webstomp.js?afe9:238 <<< CONNECTED
version:1.2
heart-beat:0,0
user-name:coach

�
webstomp.js?afe9:238 connected to server undefined
webstomp.js?afe9:238 >>> SEND
destination:/topic/activity
content-length:12

{"page":"/"}�
webstomp.js?afe9:238 >>> length 65
webstomp.js?afe9:238 >>> SEND
destination:/topic/activity
content-length:35

{"page":"/coach/client-management"}�
webstomp.js?afe9:238 >>> length 88
```

Is there a way to turn this off?

..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the stomp debug method by declaring `this.stompClient.debug = () => {}` wherever you declare the `this.stompClient`.  By default for a JHipster app, this is in `src/main/webapp/app/core/tracker/TrackerService.js`

```
    const socket = new SockJS(url);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    // add this line
    this.stompClient.debug = () => {}
    const headers = {};
    this.stompClient.connect(headers, () => {
    ....
```

You can find more information about how to use the [debug method in the STOMP docs](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/#debug):

> The client can set its debug property to a function which takes a String argument to see all the debug statements of the library:
>
> By default, the debug messages are logged in the browser window's console.

Answer (score 0):

> Can also be pass as an argument

```
const socket: WebSocket = new SockJS(url);
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket, { debug: false });
...
```